# Mp piechart size increase

Tags: android, pie-chart

I am using Mp piechart in my app. It showing very small size, I am trying to increase its size but it is not increasing its size. I am unable findout what is the problem. Please tell how is possible increase size.

Here is my code:

```
public class MPpiechart extends Activity {

private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private PieChart mChart;
// we're going to display pie chart for smartphones martket shares
private float[] yData = { 5, 10, 15, 30, 40 };
private String[] xData = { "Sony", "Huawei", "LG", "Apple", "Samsung" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.piegraph);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mChart = new PieChart(this);
    // add pie chart to main layout

    mainLayout.addView(mChart);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55656C"));

    // configure pie chart
    mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    mChart.setDescription("Smartphones Market Share");

    // enable hole and configure
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
   //mChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);
    mChart.setHoleRadius(7);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(10);

    // enable rotation of the chart by touch
    mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
    mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

    // set a chart value selected listener
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            // display msg when value selected
            if (e == null)
                return;

            Toast.makeText(MPpiechart.this,
                    xData[e.getXIndex()] + " = " + e.getVal() + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });

    // add data
    addData();

    // customize legends
    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
    l.setXEntrySpace(7);
    l.setYEntrySpace(5);
}

private void addData() {
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++)
        yVals1.add(new Entry(yData[i], i));

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++)
        xVals.add(xData[i]);

    // create pie data set
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Market Share");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);

    // add many colors
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    // instantiate pie data object now
    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.GRAY);

    mChart.setData(data);

    // undo all highlights
    mChart.highlightValues(null);

    // update pie chart
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

`Piegraph.java`

```
public class PieGraph extends View {

private Paint piePaint;
private RectF rectF;
private float[] data;

public PieGraph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);

    piePaint = new Paint();
    piePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    piePaint.setDither(true);
    piePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   /* mShadowPaint = new Paint(0);
    mShadowPaint.setColor(0xff101010);
    mShadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));*/

}

public float[] pieSegment(){

    float[] segValues = new float[this.data.length];
    float Total = getTotal();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){

        segValues[i] = (this.data[i]/Total) * 360;
    }
  //  x = ( radius of pie chart /2)*cos(angle in RADIANS) [angle in radians =    Math.toRadians(half the sweep angle in degrees)
    return segValues;
}


public float getTotal(){

    float total = 0;

    for (float val : this.data){
        total +=val;
    }

    return total;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    if (data != null){

        int top = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int endBottom = getHeight();
        int endRight = endBottom;

        rectF = new RectF(left, top, endRight, endBottom);

        float[] segment = pieSegment();

        float segStartPoint = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < segment.length; i++){

            Random rnd = new Random();

            int[] color = {getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow),
                    getResources().getColor(R.color.red),getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)};

          //  int color = Color.argb(255, (int)segment[i], rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            String[] name ={(String) getResources().getText(R.string.Energy), (String) getResources().getText(R.string.Fat),
                    (String) getResources().getText(R.string.Fiber), (String) getResources().getText(R.string.Methi)};
            piePaint.setColor(color[i]);
            canvas.drawText(name[i],segStartPoint,segment[i], piePaint);
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, segStartPoint, segment[i], true, piePaint);
            segStartPoint += segment[i];

        }
    }
}

public void setData(float[] data){

    this.data = data;
    invalidate();
}
}
```

`piegraph.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside pie data size

```
.setValueTextSize(12);
```

for center data size

```
.setCenterTextSize(30);
```